# Mobile website/app

Tags: php, html, mobile, smartphone

I am on a project to create an app form to represent various real time power data. The data is already available online (on a website). So in a way I am making an app version of the site.
However I am NOT given access to any of the back end, meaning I am not given any of PHP protocols to send real time data into my app.
 I have tried downloading the entire website, however there is a hidden php file on the site, so the downloaded version of the website does not display any data.

So I am at a road block, I want to do the work, however I simply do not even know how to begin.

I have looked into converting the website into a mobile site using tools, however this requires modifying the base website it self (which I am not given access).

If I am to code the app from scratch then I would prefer HTML 5 for cross platform, but native works as well.

Overall I am stuck, if anyone has any experience making mobile sites, app based websites etc could give some input. If I am given an impossible task please let me know. Then I can tell my professor and work something out.

Comment: get the html from the site, process the known format to fit your needs and write it back out as 'your own' html.

Comment: You need to parse the information from the website. Use HtmlUnit for web download and parse with Jsoup.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use AJAX for that?

You have to code a view that returns the HTML that you want.

For example: " http://yourserver/yourphp.php "

In your app, you can use Apache Cordova for manage the webview, and use this function to append that text response (your HTML) to your application body

```
function httpGet(yourUrl){
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", yourUrl,);
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```